# How to Select max Value from 2 tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in MySQL DB.

Both the tables have a column as **ID** which is of type **int(10) unsigned**.

Table1 has no data and Table2 has the ID as **24**.

I am using the below query to get the max ID

```
select max(ID) from 
(        
   select IFNULL(max(ID),0) as ID from table1 
   UNION 
   select IFNULL(max(ID),0) as ID from table2
)temp;
```

I am expecting the value 24 but it gives 0.

Anything wrong in my query? Please help.

Comment: [Your query returns 24](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3773/1) for me. Are you sure the actual query is exactly same as the one you've shown here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

```
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(ID), 0) ID
FROM
(
    SELECT ID FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID FROM table2
) a
```

Comment: This works perfectly. But I am not understanding what's wrong in my query? And also can you please tell that is there any better way of finding the max number from 2 tables?